# Extension in php file

Tags: php, mysqli

I created a page that can upload file to my database, but when a filename has (.), it doesnt save properly. For example I upload a file named imagefile.50.jpg, it just saves as image20.50

```
<?php

function upload_image()
{
    if(isset($_FILES["user_image"]))
    {
        $extension = explode('.', $_FILES['user_image']['name']);
        $new_name = $extension[0] . '.' . $extension[1];
        $destination = './upload/' . $new_name;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'], $destination);
        return $new_name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the `filename` and `extension` of a file, you can use [`pathinfo`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php), i.e.:

```
$file = "some_dir/somefile.test.php"; # $_FILES['user_image']['name']
$path_parts = pathinfo($file);
$fn = $path_parts['filename'];
$ext = $path_parts['extension'];
print $fn."\n";
print $ext;
```

Output:

```
somefile.test
php
```

Comment: my file is uploading properly, i just want to upload it even the file name has (.) it should upload but wont recognize any other (.) as the last extension

Comment: I'm honestly not following you.

Comment: Ok i have a upload script https://pastebin.com/AGV0zBPt that uploads file to my database, but everytime a filename has a period (.) it recognizes as an extension. For example i have a file imagename2.1.jpg, when i upload it, it becomes imagename2.1 without extension jpg.

Comment: in short, i just need the script to recognize the last period as extension

Comment: Your code just prints but doesnt move the file the upload folder

Comment: Yes, my code doesn't move anything, it just matches the correct extension.

Comment: how can i upload and move the file to the correct folder with, ive been searching and trying for hours and cant do any progress.

Comment: been reading and tried that too, i just can't get it work, can you help me?

Comment: the file is uploading properly but the filename is wrong everytime it has period it recognizes as an extension e.g image20.1.jpg shouldnt be image20.1 in upload folder